# How to use jQuery .wrap() from a specific start and end point on multiple HTML elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to use the jQuery .wrap() function to wrap a div around a range of html tags from a specific start and end point. For example, here's what my HTML document looks like now:

My current HTML structure:

```
<div class="single-post">
    <img src="" />
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

I would like to wrap a div with a class of "new" around these elements from above:

```
<p></p>
<p></p>
<blockquote></blockquote>
<p></p>
```

In effect this is what my end result should look like:

```
<div class="single-post">
    <img src="" />
    <div class="new">
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <blockquote></blockquote>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Somehow the answer using element exclusion doesn't match the question title that indicates start and end points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, assuming that img is always a lone ranger, you could do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mSmkC/2/):

jQuery:

```
$('.single-post > img').siblings().wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

---

You could also do something like [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mSmkC/4/):

```
$('.single-post').children(':not(.exclude)').wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

Comment: I actually made a mistake with my original question and just corrected it. What about wrapping these sets of above html elements?

Comment: Out of curiosity I decided to test how these 3 codes perform against each other: http://jsperf.com/wrapall-except-img - http://jsperf.com/wrapall-except-img-2

Answer (score 1):

If the first child inside `<div class="single-post">` should always be skipped:

```
$('.single-post')
    .children()
    .slice(1)
    .wrapAll('<div class="new" />');
```

Here, the first argument to `.slice()` indicates the starting point (second element). You can also specify the end point using the second argument:

```
.slice(1, 4) // will select elements 2 and 3
```

*Start and end point can be negative to mean positions from the end*

See also: [`jQuery.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)